# System Setting ties notification volume to ringer volume

Tags: android

By default Android treats the Ringer and Notification sounds as one audio stream.
To change this you sould deselect the check box labeled "Use incoming call volume for notifications" on android settings.

Is it possible to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

[Android - Toggle Notification volume programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084347/android-toggle-notification-volume-programatically)